# Enable binary logging for MSBuild in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

In order to use the [binary logging format for MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/Binary-Log) introduced in MSBuild 15.3, I have to run MSBuild and pass in the `/bl` command-line argument:

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /bl
```

How can I have Visual Studio pass this argument every time I build from within Visual Studio? Or, is there some other way to view the output from within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install the [Project System Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools) (referenced by [@MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48400911/111794)).

Also install the [MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/).

The Project System Tools adds a new **Build Logging** window. When you right-click on entries in the window and choose **Open Log...**, the log will be opened using the viewer.

Comment: Make sure to click on the *Start logging builds* button (⯈ symbol at the top left corner of the *Build Logging* window) before building your project for entries to appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, the binlog you get from the extension does not contain all the information the Structured Log Viewer can display, specifically the following are missing: *Evaluation*, *Files*, *Find in files* which are basically crucial for many types of debugging.

Comment: You need to right click on the file, open its location and open in MSBuild Log Viewer. Don't try to view it in VS.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a small extension, [Project System Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools)